# How to know the location of a point in a rotated grid with equal sized square-shaped cells

Tags: geometry, cell, trigonometry

Given a grid inclined at an angle `θ` (theta) with equal sized square-shaped cells with indices 00, 01, 02, ..., 55 (where first digit being x index and second being y index, for instance 00 means a cell at the intersection of row 0 and column 0), and a point `p(x,y)`, how can we know that in which grid cell does the point lie without checking all the cells?

For instance, in the image below point `p` lies in the cell with index 23.

[image]

I found one answer at [Checking if a point is inside a rotated rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136084/checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rotated-rectangle) that explains how to determine if a point lies inside a rotated rectangle, but with this approach I need to check all the grid cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way - rotate point by the same angle (with negative sign) and check new coordinates in axis-aligned grid

```
nx = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
ny = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
row = (int) (ny / cellsize)
col = (int) (nx / cellsize)
```

Comment: I think I am not getting the right results. Consider p(5,1), θ = 45 degrees and cellsize = 1. I am getting row = -3 and col = 3.

Comment: OK, I made sign change to use the same theta direction as for grid. Now row=2, col=4

Comment: That's great. It works. Can you explain what is happening in the above statements?

Comment: Here we apply [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to find position of point after rotation around coordinate origin

Comment: Its working, but I don' understand why its working? The rotation matrix (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is for anticlockwise rotation with respect to x-axis, whereas in my case rotation is clockwise with respect to y-axis. Yet it seems to work. What could be the reason?

Comment: We want to see point position in unrotated grid. To achieve this, we have to rotate in another direction. Your grid essentially is rotated by negative angle in usual mathematical coordinate system (where CCW is positive, CW is negative), so we make formula with positive theta value for point.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
One thing more, the solution seems to work for angles less than 90. For angles >= 90, it doesn't work.

Comment: Let angle = 135, x=0, y=-3, so nx= - (-3*0.7)=2.1  ny = -3*(-0.7)=2.1. Cell 2,2, as expected

Comment: Yes, its correct. Sorry I was mistaken about grid coordinates after its rotation. Thank you very much :)